# Using regex to filter bunch of email addresses in text with some specific conditions

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I'm experimenting with regex and I'm trying to filter out bunch of email addresses that are embedded in some text source. The filter process will be on two specific conditions:

1. Every email starts with `abc`
2. Regular email patter which includes an `@` followed by a `.` and
   ending specifically in `com`

Source:

> sajgvdaskdsdsds`abcdefghij@gmail.com`sdksdhkshdsdk`abcdefghij123@gmail.com`wdgjkasdsdad
>
> Pattern1 = "abc[\w\W]*[@][\w]*\.com

code:

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        String source = "sajgvdaskdsdsdsabcdefghij@gmail.comsdksdhkshdsdkabcdefghij123@gmail.comwdgjkasdsdad";


        String pattern1 = "abc[\\w\\W]*[@][\\w]*\\.com";

        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
        Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(source);
        System.out.println("Source:\t" + source);
        System.out.println("Exprsn:\t" + m1.pattern());
        while (m1.find())
        {
            found = true;
            System.out.println("Pos: " + m1.start() + "\tFound: " + m1.group());
        }
        System.out.println();
        if(!found)
        {
            System.out.println("Nothing found!");
        }

    }

}
```

I'm expecting o/p as:

> Pos: 15   Found: abcdefghij@gmail.com
>
> Pos: 48   Found: abcdefghij123@gmail.com

But getting:

> Pos: 15   Found:
>   abcdefghij@gmail.comsdksdhkshdsdkabcdefghij123@gmail.com

If I use this Pattern2: `abc[\\w]*[@][\\w]*\\.com` then I'm getting the expected o/p. However, the thing is email address can contain non-word characters after `abc` and before `@`. (For example: `abcd$efghi$@gmail.com`).

Hence Pattern2 doesn't work with non-word characters. So, I went with `[\\w\\W]*` instead of `[\\w]*`.

I also tried Pattern3: `abc[\\w\\W][@][\\w]\\.com[^.]` and still doesn't work.

Please help me, where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex operators are greedy by default, meaning that they will grab as much of the string as they can. `[\w\W]*` will grab all intervening `@` characters except for the very last one.

Either use the reluctant form of the operators (e.g. `*?` instead of `*`), or just simplify the expression:

```
abc[^@]*@[^.]+\.com
```

`[^@]` will take as many characters that aren't `@` as it can find. Similarly `[^.]` will match everything until the first dot.

Alternatively, you can use reluctant operators:

```
abc.*?@.*?\.com
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!! 

Should've simplified the expression using ^@ and ^.

Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Glad it helped. This is the first regex question showing a lot of effort and research I've seen in a long time. Keep it up

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask, are there patterns for saying something like this: "find me something that has exactly n number of x in a string" ? Like: "11111saksda" <-- 5 no.s of "1".

Comment: `x{n}` should do it

Comment: You can also do `x{m, n}` to indicate `x` between `m`and `n` times

Answer (score 1):

Try to exclude `'@'` from the left part:

```
"abc[\\w\\W&&[^@]]+@[\\w]+\\.com"
```

Then in the following input:

```
"sajgvdasabcd$efghi$@gmail.comkdsd" + 
"sdsabcdefghij@gmail.comsdksdhks" + 
"hdsdkabcdefghij123@gmail.comwdgjkasdsdad"
```

it matches:

```
abcd$efghi$@gmail.com
abcdefghij@gmail.com
abcdefghij123@gmail.com
```

The `[foo&&[^bar]]` syntax in the regex means: include all `foo`, but exclude all `bar`.

---

**EDIT**: the pattern `[\\w\\W&&[^@]]` is slightly nonsensical, because it's the same as `[^@]`. However, if you want to restrict `\\w\\W` to something more meaningful, it would still work.

Comment: `[\\w\\W&&[^@]]` is just a very complicated way of saying `[^@]`, but +1 for showing me that syntax. I've never seen it before.

Comment: You are right. [\\w\\W] is redundant of [^@]. Got it correct, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you. I've decided to leave it as-is, because for example, the `\\w\\W` part can be replaced by non-whitespace character class `\\S`, so that the pattern becomes `[\\S&&[^@]]`, which is both more meaningful and more specific than just `[^@]`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first character class - `\\w` includes all [word-characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html), [a-zA-Z_0-9].  `\\W` is just the complement of this, so I putting these together is capable of matching anything.  Ideally you'd use a whitelist of the characters you expect in here (`\n` probably isn't allowed!), but the key thing is that you definitely don't want @, so this will give you the two matches:

```
"abc[^@]*[@][\\w]*\\.com"
```

I'd suggest that the other square brackets are superfluous, so should be removed, and that that second group should really have at least one character.  This would leave you with:

"abc[^@]*@\w+\.com"

Comment: Thank you. I was going through topic of meta-characters mainly and was thinking in that point of view..hence did not thought of a ^@. I got that corrected, thank you! :)